# Get latest uploads using the v3 version of YouTube gData

Tags: youtube-api, gdata

Does anyone know how to get the latest uploads for a specific channel (or user will do too)?

In v2 of the gdata api you had the 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/[username]/uploads?alt=json' call. But that's deprecated. In v3 there's the `youtube.activities.list` function, but that doesn't give the same results.

I thought I could get the playlists first, but than I seem to be missing some uploads that are not in a playlist.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the lastest uploads of a specific channel, don't pass by : `youtube.activities.list`.

The YouTube API V3 provide a special playlist of the uploads.
To get the id of the playlist two important link :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?hl=fr
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?hl=fr

And the two steps to get the uploads :

You need to use `youtube.channel.list` with the parameters :

```
part=contentDetails
id=ID_OF_THE_CHANNEL
```

The result is like this :

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"kjEFmP90GvrCl8BObMQtGoRfgaQ/CMNDR4CfkeuPx4qnAlqzH11BB5A\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"kjEFmP90GvrCl8BObMQtGoRfgaQ/MeyW1Z8CbXCFwqPMlOLEwNZyMc0\"",
   "id": "UCzOpxz1sdfp_0eRYqXkoSNA",
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "likes": "qsdqsxz1y8np_0eRYqXkoSNA",
     "uploads": "qsdqsd1y8np_0eRYqXkoSNA"
    },
    "googlePlusUserId": "151...45515"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The playlist id of the uploads : `items -> contentDetails -> uploads`

Now you need to call the API a second time with `youtube.playlistItems.list` with the parameters :

```
part=snippet
playlistId=ID_OF_THE_PLAYLIST_UPLOADS
```

The result is like this :

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"kjEFmP90GvrCl8BObMQtGoRfgaQ/bS4qNeqE0hEI-qb_r8hcbN9G1sE\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 38,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"kjEFmP90GvrCl8BObMQtGoRfgaQ/ItttPAEwALDI0QdLoylbdN6oHcY\"",
   "id": "UUT2INYKRKg8bTaC4Z8-faCKSOt7nfZDHN",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-08-12T09:45:41.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCM1Bnpxipb8H4GJoITnJ0XQ",
    "title": "Trollsky making a small wood carving knife",
    "description": "Music by Witek Kulczycki\nhttps://itunes.apple.com/pl/album/monaghan-single/id905434557\nhttp://www.cdbaby.com/Artist/WitekKulczycki",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bTD8U2fcG-Y/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bTD8U2fcG-Y/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bTD8U2fcG-Y/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bTD8U2fcG-Y/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Trollskyy",
    "playlistId": "UUM1Bnpxipb8H4GJoITnJ0XQ",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "bTD8U2fcG-Y"
    }
   }
  },
  ...
```

The uploads are sort by date. Lastest upload is the top of the list.

Hope it's help !

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I just didn't hit the right combination of parameters yet.